# {DataFrameWriter CSV to HDFS file system} write data without partitioning

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

here, df is our data frame in which we are having our output, As i'm using dataframewriter to write the whole output to directory, but all the data is getting partitioned as mentioned below..

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /path to hdfs directory..

Found 4 items

-rw-r--r--   3 xxxxxx xxxxxxx          0 2022-04-28 23:19 path to hdfs directory../_SUCCESS

-rw-r--r--   3 xxxxxx xxxxxx        238 2022-04-28 23:19 path to hdfs directory../part-00000-4bc48c17-5c85-44be-bf34-3645d2b2e085-c000.csv

-rw-r--r--   3 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx    6204498 2022-04-28 23:19 path to hdfs directory../part-00043-4bc48c17-5c85-44be-bf34-3645d2b2e085-c000.csv

-rw-r--r--   3 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx    5875627 2022-04-28 23:19 path to hdfs directory../part-00191-4bc48c17-5c85-44be-bf34-3645d2b2e085-c000.csv
```

I want all the data into one single CSV file, is there any other option put in the code.. below

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv('path to hdfs directory', header = True, sep = ',')
```

the data is about 55k rows in the df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `coalesce(1)` to make a single CSV file

```py
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv('path to hdfs directory', header = True, sep = ',')
```